# corrupted text characters with Imagemagick label:

Tags: imagemagick, google-cloud-functions

I'm running into a strange bug that I cannot reproduce locally. But on Google Cloud Functions, the same text usually does the same thing, but it too has been somewhat of a rolling issue - sometimes it happens, then magically goes away.

[image: corrupted character sample]

Here's a sample of the convert call and the resulting corrupt text:

```
convert -background none -stroke "rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.0)" -fill "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)" -font ./fonts/FrederickatheGreat-Regular.ttf -pointsize 68 label:"Carly" -trim \( +clone -background "rgba(135, 138, 140, 0.59)" -shadow 80x8+8+10 \) +swap -background none -layers merge +repage -rotate 0 /tmp/1057522377634683.png
```

[image: The above code made the "Carly" text and the same code made the "Sarah" but with the label changed.]

The version of ImageMagick running on GCF is:

> convert -version: Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-07-15
>   http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014
>   ImageMagick Studio LLC Features: DPC Modules OpenMP Delegates: bzlib
>   cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma
>   openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib

I have the same version of Imagemagick on my local machine, but cannot reproduce the text corruption. I suspect it could be with the compile version that's live on Google (note the 2017-7-15 compile date)

I'm hoping someone has run into this in the past and knows what an easy fix is - is it an issue with supplying RGBA values, .png output type, etc.

Comment: Check your versions of Freetype delegate used by ImageMagick to deal with font rendering. That version of ImageMagick is also about 120 versions old. But it looks to be patched. Sometimes patches are bad or are not installed or installed poorly. So, yes, it could be the Google environment of ImageMagick.

Comment: Hi @fmw42 - thanks for the comment. I actually sorted it out. So, the command I am using is using the `label:` option and I was specifing a `-stroke` but no `-strokewidth` and I'm not entirely sure that these are supported by the `label` option...they are with `-draw` but I've not figured out how to do the drop shadow with `-draw`. Anyhow, I got rid of the funky characters by removing the `-stoke` value.

Comment: Stroke and stroke width are supported by label:. But I was puzzled why you had a fully transparent stroke.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the `-stoke` option without a `-strokewidth` being set - also I'm not 100% sure whether or not `label` supports those or not, I'll have to test later. But my solution was to remove the `-stroke` from the command and the font characters stopped being corrupt.

Comment: I ran your command 20 times using ImageMagick 6.9.9.23 Q16 Mac OSX with no errors and the result looked fine. I suspect either 6.8.9.9 is flawed or your Freetype delegate is old on the machine that fails. However, I see no reason to use a fully transparent stroke. Perhaps that is just what you had and are allowing other colors. Similarly for -rotate 0, which is a no-op, but will process anyway.